# How to select a range of values by searching a factor column in time format hh:mm:ss

Tags: r, sorting, time

I have data that i would like to pull from a specific time frame. I can not figure out how to tell r to separate all the data between 13:52:07 and 14:12:00 for example. I assume my problem lies with the fact that my time column is labeled as a factor.

Ive tried

```
calibration1<-subset(trial,Time >= "13:52:50" & Time <= "14:12:00", select=c(CH.2.O2, CH.4.O2))
```

But it would appear that r can not figure out how to deal with the time format as a factor.

Warning messages:

```
1: In Ops.factor(Time, "13:52:50") : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(Time, "14:12:00") : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: It would be helpful to others to help if you can provide reproducible data.

Comment: maybe do e.g. `as.character(Time) >= "13:52:50"`

Comment: If you've loaded the dataframe from elsewhere and keep running into this problem, in your `read.csv` you can use `stringsAsFactors=F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to convert to `times` (from `chron`) and then do the comparison

```
library(chron)
trial$Time <- times(trial$Time)
subset(trial,Time >= times("13:52:50") & Time <= times("14:12:00"), 
              select=c(CH.2.O2, CH.4.O2))
```